# How to get child count of a parent from Firebase using PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an application like facebook to create posts and users can comment and like to the posts. I use firebase realtime database to store likes and comments data for posts. Follow the image below,

[image]

Now I need to get the posts to ascending order by comments count and likes count. How can I do this using PHP ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an unofficial Admin SDK for PHP at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php that makes this fairly easy.

Once [installed](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#installation) and [set up](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html), you can do this:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('/path/to/credentials.json');

$firebase = (new Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$db = $firebase->getDatabase();

echo count($db->getReference('path/to/comments')->shallow()->getValue());
```

I don't know a more comfortable way to do it in PHP  (Disclaimer: I created the SDK )